# Did Churches plant a tree at their entrance in 13th century Christian Spain?

Tags: church-history, historic-customs

Nahmanides (in his commentary to Deut. 16:22) writes that the Christians in his time had a custom of planting a tree at the entrance of their Churches.

Is there any corroboration validating the claim of such a custom at all, especially in Nahmanides' time and place (13th century Christian Spain)?

Her is the original Hebrew:

> [פסוק כב (כל הפסוק)](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%96#)
>
> "ולא תקים לך מצבה" - מצבת אבן אחת להקריב עליה אפילו לשמים אשר שנא מזבח אדמה ומזבח אבנים צוה לעשות ואת זו שנא כי חוק היתה לכנענים ואע"פ שהיתה אהובה לו בימי האבות עכשיו שנאה מאחר שעשאוה אלו חוק לע"ז לשון רש"י ואם כן אסר הכתוב האשרה ואסר כל נוטע בהר הבית אע"פ שכוונתו לשמים ואסר המצבה לשמים ושניהם מפני חוקת הכנעניים אבל לא הבינותי החק הזה שהרי הכנעניים גם במזבחות גם במצבות היו נוהגים שהכתוב אומר ונתצתם את מזבחותם ושברתם את מצבותם (לעיל יב ג) כי את מזבחותם תתצון ואת מצבותם תשברון (שמות לד יג) וכן בכל מקום ואולי נאמר שהחזיקו הכנענים במצבות ולא היה להם בית ע"ז שאין שם מצבה להקטיר עליה ולצוק שמן על ראשה וכענין שנאמר בבעל (מלכים ב י כו) ויוציאו את מצבות בית הבעל אבל המזבחות היו במקצתן להקריב גם בהם והנראה בעיני כי היו הכנענים השטופים בע"ז עושים בכל בתי אלהיהם מזבח להקריב עליו הקרבנות ואבן גדולה מוצבת על פתח הבית לעמוד עליה הכומרים ואילן נטוע חוצה לה לאשר דרך הבאים שם וגם היום הנוצרים עושים כן והנה השם הנכבד שנא ומאס כל מעשיהם ואסר המצבה והאשרה ולא השאיר רק המזבח שהוא צורך הקרבנות אשר הוא יתברך צוה בהם והיו נחת רוח לפניו שאמר ונעשה רצונו מאז קודם היות ע"ז בעולם וטעם אשר שנא ביאור כי השם צוה (שמות כ כד כה) מזבח אדמה תעשה לי ואם מזבח אבנים תעשה לי וביאר משה כי באלה יחפוץ להוציא המצבה כי שנאה כי כל מעשיהם שנואין לפניו וצוה את ישראל שלא יעשו כמעשיהם אבל בימי יעקב לא נאמר עדיין ובחקותיהם לא תלכו (ויקרא יח ג) ולכך היה משתמש במצבה לשם שמים כמנהג העובדים והנה זו מצוה מבוארת מן ואם מזבח אבנים תעשה לי אבל מה שאמר בתורה (שם כו א) ופסל ומצבה לא תקימו לכם הם פסל ומצבה להושיב הפסל על המצבה לע"ז כי שם בענין ע"ז דיבר הכתוב אבל יאמר (שם) ואבן משכית לא תתנו בארצכם להשתחוות עליה אפילו לשמים מפני שהוא נראה כעובד לשכיות ההם כטעם האשרה שהיא מחוקות העמים ודע כי מזבח הוא בנין אבנים גבוה ולו קרנות ארבע ולו יסוד סובב יעלו על יסודו ומקריבים בין קרנותיו והמצבה אבן אחת גדולה ירימוה להקטיר או להקריב עליה או להיות הכומרים עומדים עליה והבמה כענין הר ועושים אותה מעפר מקובץ ועליה מזבח בנוי להקריב בו כי כל דבר רם וגבוה יקראו כן אעלה על במתי עב (ישעיהו יד יד) על במותי ארץ (דברים לב יג) גם גב האדם יקרא במה על במותימו תדרך (שם לג כט) וכן אמר הכתוב (מלכים א ג ד) וילך המלך גבעונה לזבוח שם כי היא הבמה הגדולה אלף עולות יעלה שלמה על המזבח ההוא

Comment: Would it be possible to add a link as to where you read this. This may have been a local tradition to the area of medieval Catalonia.

Comment: @KenGraham I read it in the original Hebrew in Nahmandides' commentary to the Torah. Available for free on the Hebrew Wikisource: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%96#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.9B.D7.91_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes, I am looking for outside corroboration besides Nahmanides' statement. I edited the question to clarify that point.

Comment: Obviously we must have an accurate English translation in order to understand any nuances involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Did Churches plant a tree at their entrance in 13th century Christian Spain?**

The short answer would seems that **it was quite possible, but it was never a universal practice or tradition in Spain or any other European country for that matter.** It is not unheard of as a way of beautifying the grounds around a church, monastery or cathedral. It was definitely not a local custom, but it probably existed here and there, as the the desire of the local clergy and religious authorities wished.

This type of landscape design exists in here and there in modern days. Westminster Abbey (Mission, BC) in an example of such an existing custom. The Abbey Church was was consecrated in 1982 by Cardinal Basil Hume.

[image: Westminster Abbey (British Columbia)]

[Westminster Abbey (British Columbia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Abbey_(British_Columbia))

Moving a little closer to Spain, we can see [St Edward's Church](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/st-edwards-church), Stow-on-the-Wold, England has trees in front of the church in such a way that even JR Tolkien would be in awe.

**At least this church takes us to the 13th century.**

> This medieval sanctuary's tree-framed door looks like a portal to a mythical realm.
>
> **Bound by two ancient yew trees**, this door looks more like a portal to a fairy realm than a church entrance. The arched wooden opening, capped by colorful stained glass windows, beckons visitors to unleash their imaginations and fantasize about the magical worlds that may be hiding on the other side.
>
> Given the entry’s enchanting appearance, there’s little wonder why local lore says it inspired J.R.R. Tolkien’s Doors of Durin. Like this door, those elven entrances were flanked by two magnificent trees.
>
> People speculate the writer came across the door during one of his many visits to the Cotswolds. But as exciting as the legendary connection is, there’s no proof that the link between the English church and Tolkien’s creations is true, making the theory just as fantastical as the author’s stories.
>
> Even without a concrete Tolkien connection, St Edward’s Church is well worth visiting. The structure was built in the Middle Ages and is now a medley of fixtures from various centuries. Explore the building and you’ll find fragments dating from the 1000s through the 1600s, as well as pieces installed during Victorian-era restorations. Its tree-framed north door was constructed during the 13th century.

[image: St Edward's Church, Stow-on-the-Wold]

[St Edward's Church, Stow-on-the-Wold](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Edward%27s_Church,_Stow-on-the-Wold)

Now if other countries in the 13th century had trees in front of their churches, logic dictates that in the same time frame, there must have been some Catholic Churches in Spain with trees planted in front of their facades.

> The yew (tree) is traditionally and regularly found in churchyards in England, Wales, Scotland, Ireland and Northern France (particularly Normandy). Some examples can be found in La Haye-de-Routot or La Lande-Patry. - [Taxus baccata (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxus_baccata)

To finish the question off, let us that a little walk down memory lane and look at the [Cathedral of Seville with its orange tree courtyard](https://devoursevillefoodtours.com/seville-oranges/)!

> Not just a pretty face, Seville’s orange trees are more than just a form of natural decor for the city centre.
>
> From the intoxicating smell of the azahar, or orange blossoms, in springtime, to the practical use of the fruit in marmalade fit for a queen (literally!), the orange trees of Seville form a unique part of the city’s history.
>
> This naranja amarga, or bitter orange, was later introduced to Europe by Genovese sailors, who brought it over from Asia. Rumored to bring happiness to whoever possessed it, the Moorish dynasty that reigned at the time decided to plant these bitter orange trees all over Spain, with a high concentration of them in Andalusia.
>
> **By the 12th century, everyone was a firm believer of the happiness-inducing qualities of the bitter orange. They began to plant them along the streets, and by the end of the century, even went so far as to construct the Patio de los Naranjos at the Cathedral of Seville.**

[image: The serene orange tree courtyard offers a perfect spot to relax outside the cathedral]

**The serene orange tree courtyard offers a perfect spot to relax outside the cathedral.**